# Why would list-style items still show even though set to none?

Tags: css, wordpress

Not a css ninja, but from what I know setting

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none
}
```

should remove the bullet points from a list. However, that doesn't seem to work in my case.

The element in question is on this page on the right hand side of the footer.

Hints & help very much appreciated!

EDIT: Removed link because not relevant anymore.

Comment: it works fine, you need to refresh your browser and reload the page

Comment: @G-Cyr, did you visit the link? The bullet points are clearly visible where OP said...

Comment: @Ryan i did visit the link else i would not react (FF latest/ W7 ) , it was about the footer

Comment: @G-Cyr not sure what you saw, but after your comment I tried hard refreshs, removing cookies and browsers I rarely use to check if the bullets would disappear. They didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

List style type needs to be added to the UL and not the individual item (li).

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

List style is added to the individual item (li).

```
ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

However, on your webpage, custom bullet points are being added using pseudeo elements (:before, :after). Add `display: none` as below

```
.footer-widget li:before {
     display: none;
}
```

Comment: Wasn't  aware of the difference between list-style-type and list-style (only used list-style-type but added list-style out of desperation), thanks for educating me. Also thank you for providing the solution!